# What are the most severe possible sentences faced by the three accused Russian spies?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, england-and-wales, espionage

Three Bulgarian National alleged Russian spies have been arrested and charged in the UK. What is their worst possible outcome on the other end of this?

Comment: Relevant [BBC article](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.bbc.com/news/uk-66504350.amp)

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that the investigation in to alleged spying is on going and yet to be concluded, and they have only been charged with a [section 4](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/40/section/4?timeline=false) Identity Documents Act 2010 offence: *Possession of false identity documents etc with improper intention*.

The *maximum* sentence is at s.4(4):

> (4)A person guilty of an offence under this section is liable, on conviction on indictment, to **imprisonment for a term not exceeding 10 years or a fine (or both)**.

<strike>If they are ultimately charged with [assisting a foreign intelligence service](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/national-security-bill-factsheets/espionage-etc-national-security-bill-factsheet#:%7E:text=The%20Official%20Secrets%20Act%201911,%27useful%20to%20an%20enemy%27.) under the Official Secrets Act, the maximum penalty is 14 years.</strike>

There's also the possibility of being deported at the end of (and occasionally instead of, or completing in their home country) any sentence under [section 3(5)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/77/section/3?timeline=false), Immigration Act 1971:

> (5)A person who is not a British citizen is liable to deportation from the United Kingdom if—
>
> - (a)the Secretary of State deems his deportation to be conducive to the public good; or
> - (b)another person to whose family he belongs is or has been ordered to be deported.

[*(3)(5)(b) might, for example, be applicable if only one of the married couple was convicted*]

What the potential sentence is, if any, for alleged spying will only be known if/when charges are brought.

Comment: Your second link describes the National Security Act 2023 which only came into effect this July, while the defendants were arrested back in February.

Comment: As to the National Security Act 2023 (if it applied), you may have overlooked Section 1, "Obtaining or disclosing protected information", which is punishable by life imprisonment.  Previous legislation probably had a similar provision.

Comment: @NateEldredge That addition was made by someone else (who probably should've know better) and TBH I ignored it; so good spot. I answered according to the known facts, deliberately avoiding the allegations of spying until further, accurate information is available.